# MySQL SELECT - Same record must match more values

Tags: mysql

I have a table `prices` with 4 columns (`id`, `price1`, `price2`, `date`)
Some explanation:

- id is NOT set to auto increment and there can be many of ID's with same
  value (i.E. Id 123 can exist 5 times but has different parameters).
- price1 and  price2  are two decimal values which store the price1 as the beginning price and price2 as the final price
- date is  VARCHAR ( 15) and stores the price date in codes (like 'J2015' -- January, 2015) and is somekind of ID for the app that's using it.

A normal query to i.E.  select Id, price1 and price2 worked with the query

```
SELECT `id`, `price1`, `price2` 
FROM `prices` 
WHERE `price1` = '1.23' AND `price='3.45' AND `date`='J2015'
```

But then a customer wanted an extended search. He wanted all IDs that pass the following criteria (example:)

**price1** = '1.50' AND **price2** = '1.75' AND **date** = 'AP2013'
and also
**price1** = '1.39' AND **price2** = '1.45' AND **date** = 'MAY2013'

At first I wanted to use the IN parameter but that would/could return incorrect data. So I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: @Mihai That will return IDs that match either criteria, not just the ones that match both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self-JOIN

```
SELECT p1.id
FROM prices AS p1
JOIN prices AS p2 ON p1.id = p2.id
WHERE p1.price1 = '1.50' AND p1.price2 = '1.75' AND p1.date = 'AP2013'
AND p2.price1 = '1.39' AND p2.price2 = '1.45' AND p2.date = 'MAY2013'
```

Comment: Thank you! After trying this code out, everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
SELECT id 
FROM prices
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM prices WHERE price1 = '1.50' AND price2 = '1.75' AND date = 'AP2013')
AND (price1 = '1.39' AND price2 = '1.45' AND date = 'MAY2013');
```